# Repeating table with new text field value

Tags: forms, infopath, repeat

I currently have a form in InfoPath with a repeating table eg:

```
Author | Location | Book (repeating table)
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
Author | Location | Book (Title1),Book (Title2),Book (Title3) etc
```

I understand that this is a short explanation - so feel free to request further info, if needed.

The Book field writes the first entry, ignoring book2, book3 etc.    I need the field to work like an array field1(book1),field2(Book2), etc.    Everytime the text field is repeated a new field should be created, saving the value.

Comment: If you know it's a short explanation, and if you have more relevant information that could help us help you, why not just put everything you know in the question in advance? For example, what have you already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: The Book field writes the first entry, ignoring book2, book3 etc.    I need the field to work like an array field1(book1),field2(Book2), etc.    Everytime the text field is repeated a new field should be created, saving the value.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions to include these details. It's harder to find the relevant information in the comments section :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a nested repeating table. Here's an example with the nested table having just one column (you can delete the header row).

[image]